# SSMS and stored procedure both return 1 but Database.SqlQuery returns 0

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

This routine returns false. The single row exists with one column but the value is 0.

The same query run from SSMS or read from a stored procedure returns 1.

```
public Boolean SnapshotExists(string name) 
{
    FormattableString sql = $"USE MASTER; SELECT count(*) as Count FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '{name}' AND source_database_id IS NOT NULL";

    List<Int32> result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Int32>(sql).ToList();

    return result[0] > 0;
}
```

If I try to create the List as List of string, it complains about casting an Int32 to a string.

I'd really rather not have to create this stored procedure on every machine that needs to run the unit tests locally, otherwise, I'd just use that code.

For comparison, here is reading the results from the stored procedure:

```
public Boolean SnapshotExists2(string name) 
{
    SqlConnection conn = (SqlConnection)Database.GetDbConnection();           
    conn.Open();

    // 1. create a command object identifying the stored procedure
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SnapshotExists", conn);
        
    // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // 3. add parameter to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
    //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", custId));

    // execute the command
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
    {
        // iterate over results, printing each to console
        rdr.Read(); 
        return ((int)rdr["Count"] > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `WHERE name = '{name}'` should be `WHERE name = {name}` it's fully parameterized using the format string so doesn't need quotes. Side note: `sys.databases` can be accessed from anywhere, you don't need the `USE`

Comment: @Charlieface I don't know why that works, but it does. The other two approaches both require the quotes. Can you add this as an answer?

Comment: Why don't you understand how it works? The query is parameterized into `WHERE name = @name` and parameters don't need and must not be quoted. Otherwise you are effectively doing `WHERE name = '@name'`

Comment: And given that it's highly unlikely you have a database named `[@name]`, the query never returns a value.

Answer (score 0):

Like [@Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) mentioned on comment, you can update `SnapshotExists` to be like this:

```
   public Boolean SnapshotExists(string name) {
        FormattableString sql = $"SELECT count(*) as Count FROM sys.databases WHERE name = {name} AND source_database_id IS NOT NULL";
        List<Int32> result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Int32>(sql).ToList();
    return result[0] > 0;
}
```

Here is the supporting articles:

https://cmatskas.com/ef-core-string-interpolation-and-sql-injection/

Comment: Others usually go to answer section to check for solution. Only a few check the comment section. It's weird to have this question answered without answer post.

Comment: But, if @Charlieface create an answer post, I will delete mine

Comment: Noted. Turn it on. Thanks, Dale

Comment: I'll give Charlieface a couple more days. If he doesn't post an answer, I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think something odd is at play.

```
$"USE MASTER; SELECT count(*) as Count FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '{name}' AND source_database_id IS NOT NULL";
```

is a string format expression, and has nothing to do with parameterization. (And you should be very careful with where the name parameter can be coming from because this is open to SQL injection.) If you do "WHERE name = {name}" should ***should*** get an exception if you pass it a value like "master" or a database name because the SQL generated would be "WHERE name = master" rather than "WHERE name = 'master'" where it would try to match a name column against a master column which does not exist. This is what happens if you use a a string type.  Which leads me to suspect this `FormattedString` type and whatever `SqlQuery` extension method is being called to parse it. I found no `SqlQuery(FormattedString)` extension method in EF, only `SqlQuery(string)`.

What may be happening which makes it appear to work is either that this extension method for `FormattedString` is somehow parameterizing the values and does not want the single quotes. I would check the SQL that actually gets executed, or try renaming the "name" parameter to something like "tableName" to ensure that it isn't doing something that may be producing a false positive resulting in SQL something like "WHERE name = name" or the like, invalidating the actual name condition.

I used the following test using a `string` type:

```
        string name = "model";
        string sql = $"USE MASTER; SELECT count(*) as Count FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '{name}'";
        using (var context = new TestDbContext())
        {
            List<Int32> result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Int32>(sql).ToList();
        }
```

This returned the expected results, however with the original query if I added the "AND source_database_id IS NOT NULL" then I got a 0 result because all databases in my particular schema had this value set to #null.  This is vulnerable to SQL Injection so a better implementation would be:

```
string sql = $"USE MASTER; SELECT count(*) as Count FROM sys.databases WHERE name = @name AND source_database_id IS NOT NULL";
List<Int32> result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Int32>(sql, new SqlParameter("name", name)).ToList();
```

... provided your database you are checking for has a source_database_id set, and it will probably work. I would be curious what this `SqlQuery` extension that accepts a `FormattedString` is actually doing. I suspect it may be trying to do something similar to parameterize the expression but getting gunked up by the quoted value. I would be wary of using such a `FormattedString` variation even if the extension method does the parameterization. It might be easy to overlook a query slipping through using a `string` and exposing a potential SQL injection rather than structuring the queries explicitly with parameterization.